# create a regular expression for following values

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression such that it can accept following values:-

```
100, 100.00, (100),(100.00),$100, $100.00, $(100), $(100.00)
```

and I am succeed in building the following regular expression:-

```
/^(\$?(?=\d*(\.\d{1,3})?$))|^(\$?\((?=\d*(\.\d{1,3})?\)$))/
```

but above regex fails if the value is just $

I want if the value is just $ then it should give not accept it..

But at the same time it should accept blank value also..

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your integer part is never optional, so you should make sure the regex makes it mandatory (right now, even the empty string would pass your regex):

```
/^\$?(?:\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$|\(\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?\)$)/
```

`\d+` means "one or more digits".

Comment: @NSS So just change it to `/^$|.../`?

Comment: thanx dude.. i got ans myself.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my regex as :

```
^(\$?(?=\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$))|^(\$?\((?=\d+(\.\d{1,3})?\)$))|^((?=\d*(\.\d{1,3})?$))
```

and its working for me..